# Executing Git server commands through Python shell

Tags: python, git, ssh

I'm trying to write my own shell script in Python for SSH to call to (using the SSH command= parameters in authorized_keys files).  Currently I'm simply calling the original SSH command (it is set as an environment variable prior to the script being called my SSH).  However, I always end up with a git error regarding the repository hanging up unexpectedly.

My Python code is literally:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess

if os.environ('SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND') is not None:
    subprocess.Popen(os.environ('SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND'), shell=True)
else:
    print 'who the *heck* do you think you are?'
```

Please let me know what is preventing the git command from successfully allowing the system to work.  For reference, the command that is being called on the server when a client calls `git push` is `git-receive-pack /path/to/repo.git`.

Regarding the Python code shown above, I have tried using `shell=True` and `shell=False` (correctly passing the command as a list when `False`) and neither work correctly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!

You'll need to call the `communicate()` method of the subprocess object created by `Popen` call.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False)
proc.communicate()
```

I'm not entirely sure why, however I think it has to do with the `communicate()` method allowing data to also be given via `stdin`.  I thought the process would automatically accept input since I didn't override the input stream at all anywhere, but perhaps a manual call to communicate is needed to kick things off...hopefully someone can weigh in here!

You also can't `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` as it will cause the command to hang.  Again, not sure if this is because of how `git` works or something to do about the whole process.  Hopefully this at least helps someone in the future!